# Launching an Android Emulator from Python-Django

Tags: android, python, django, web-applications

```
def start_test(request):
    os.system('echo Starting emulator...')
    os.system('./android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/emulator -avd testavd &')
    return HttpResponse("OK")
```

Here is the barebones code of what I am trying to do.
When this code gets executed, the server stops responding while running the emulator. Any help appreciated.
I am using the django development server. Here is the server output:

```
Django version 1.1.1, using settings 'Cloust.settings'
Development server is running at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Starting emulator...
[21/Apr/2011 02:00:06] "GET /start_test/a.apk/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5
emulator: warning: opening audio output failed

emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentred
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? The emulator will run on the server, and won't be visible from the client. What's the point?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman: I have a little more time today, so to properly answer your question, the emulator will be accessible via VNC. More specifically, using TightVNC and guacamole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still haven't gotten around to properly solving this problem, but using subprocess.Popen allows me to perform commands on the emulator afterwards:

```
print 'Starting emulator...'
subprocess.Popen(['emulator', '-avd', 'testavd'])
os.system('adb wait-for-device')
os.system('Perform whatever adb commands you need')
```

It's worth noting that this is using the django development server, which has been started using sudo, so obviously this is far from ideal.

Comment: Heey Mark, I am able to launch my AVD. But I need to launch a clean  AVD, like wipe the user data and launch a new one. How should I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should try to run emulator in separate thread?

E.g.

```
import subprocess
thread = threading.Thread(target=subprocess.popen(['./android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/emulator', '-avd', 'testavd', '&'])
thread.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering you are using django you will probably need to manage the emulators somehow.
Threading is not really a good option in this case I think.

I'd suggest looking into task management in this case with something like http://code.google.com/p/django-tasks/

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it will help so one (hope it does).

I wanted the emulator to open before automation testing starts and for some reson appium can't do it.
in my case I needed to add the full path of the emulator.

```
check_output(["/Users/{USER_NAME}/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator", "-avd", "Pixel_API_26"])
```

Hope it will help someone until appium will fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

One problem with ADB is that you need multiple commands to get things done.
For example:

```
adb shell

su 

cp /data/local/x /data/local/y

exit

adb pull /data/local/y
```

Can this be done using python popen and os-system?  Tried the example below without success..

```
print 'Starting emulator...'
subprocess.Popen(['emulator', '-avd', 'testavd'])
os.system('adb wait-for-device')
os.system('Perform whatever adb commands you need')
```